ADP5304 - circuit schematics on the datasheet not working
I've implemented the ADP5304, marking "LT9 #IT" in one of my PCB designs however it is not working as intended.
The VIN input is the typical 5V DC from a USB port, labeled VIN on the circuit schematics. The IC does not output, labeled 3V3_STDY, any kind of voltage.  The VIN OK pin also outputs 0V.  No short circuit was detected when measuring with a multimeter
The capacitors are 2x 0603 10V 10uF SMD and the inductor a 2.2uH 0603 SMD. You can find a web-based interactive view of the circuit schematics and also of the PCB layout on this repository on GitHub:
https://github.com/aeonSolutions/AeonLabs-Monitor-Fresh-Reinforced-concrete-Hardening-Strength-maturity
Can anyone assist me on this one? Below is a snapshot of the circuit schematics and the PCB layout, both on  Kicad.
Circuit Schematics in KiCad

PCB layout in KiCad

After component assembly, all circuitry is tested and passed, on first power with 5V DC from a USB connector, the IC shorts to ground permanently on pad 9 SW.
More information about the ADP5304 Datasheet and Product Info can be found here:
https://www.analog.com/en/products/adp5304.html

The VINOK never outputs voltage itself, it is an open-drain output. What do you use for the inductor and the input and output capacitors?  What load you have on the 3V3 output?

True. VINOK is an open drain pin. The capacitors are 2x 0603 10V 10uF SMD and the inductor a 2.2uH 0603 SMD

Is the NC pin ok to be connected to ground?

NC PIN2  is connected to ground...

@MiguelTomás Those details are what I can read myself from the schematics, and that still won't tell the details of the components or suitability for the job they need to do. Now, which inductor is it, which capacitor it is, which exact parts you bought to build this circuit?

@Ralph The datasheet says to connect the NC pin to ground.

I'm using a high frequency inductor. That Saud, and after more than one week, while reading your answers I decided to verify the labeling of my components. As it turned out the inductor I was using was 2.2 nano H and it needs to be a 2.2 micro H . IT IS NOW WORKING as intended . Thank you

BTW, using a 2.2 nanoH inductor burns the ADP5304 IC .

The VIN OK pin (VINOK) indicates if the input voltage is within the operating range. If this pin is outputting 0V, it suggests the IC does not detect a valid input voltage.

Another important and useful detail is that the inductor cannot be one of those ferrite SMD type of inductors. I just tried with one, and the ADP5304 is strangely outputting 4.3V !!  and with a R VID =500R!

@liaifat85 there is no circuit for the pin to show any other voltage than 0V so measuring the pin voltage is useless.

"IT IS NOW WORKING as intended" - no, this layout will never work as intended. Please compare the OEM suggested layout from your own link with your skinny traces. Please don't come back and ask why your design has too much of ripples, some voltages do not have any output, or why the efficiency is so low or EMI is so high unless you make your layout similar to the suggested one.

I have on idea what are you ranting about ....

Miguel, It shows that you have no idea about the switching regulators design. Ever heard about high-current paths in switching power design? 80% of the success in this kind of design is in careful board layout. And in proper component selection and placement. It is highly recommended, especially for novices, to follow board layouts suggested by OEM and their advice on components exactly, you will save a lot of your time.

ok ok. Since then I've altered the PCB design and moved that 3V3_STBY copper track to the bottom layer.  bellow the IC . the same with the VIN track to pin 1. Finally replaced the inductor 0805 for a 1206. .... among other little details to improve ground connectivity.
